# Can't browse Internet in Redhat 7

Tags: networking, rhel, ping

I installed RHEL 7 using server with GUI with no added option on my local virtualbox, but I cannot get Firefox connected to the Internet.

1. I checked `/etc/resolv.conf` contains nameserver setting
2. I can `ping` other servers, such as 8.8.8.8
3. I open the firewall config GUI, I can see connected is at the left corner, I added `http`, `https` and `80`, `443`, `8080` and `8443` in public zone, and set interface to use public zone

Firefox cannot get connected, and I can't `curl` either. Could some RHEL experts explain what I am missing?

Comment: Can you ping www.google.com ?

Comment: Can you ping your default gateway/router/internal network from virtualbox?Did you use static ip or DHCP? Temporary disable firewall and try to connect to internet.

Answer (score 1):

Despite having checked `/etc/resolv.conf` you must make sure that DNS is actually working. Try to make a simple request such as `dig www.google.com` and see whether you get a response.

If that works you can try to manually open a connection with telnet like this:

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question

I was using VirtualBox 4.3.14 on Windows host, after upgraded to latest 4.3.22 everything start working. Without any RHEL config changes.